# why is the Ramsey number $R(3,4)$ not equal to $R(3,3)$?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, ramsey-theory

I understand why R(3,3) is equal to 6 since we have a clique of 3 in a graph of 6 vertices. What I don't understand is that by definition of Ramsay number it says that for a R(r,s) we have to find a clique of either 3 or 4 in size. In this case, we can find a clique of 3 in a graph of 6 nodes unconditionally. Could someone explain to this hopeless student why R(3,4) = 9?

Comment: You are misunderstanding the definition of R(r,s). The definition of R(3,4) is that for any coloring of edges of a complete on this many vertices with red and blue, we will have either a red clique on 3 vertices or a blue clique on 4 vertices. The reason this needn't be the same as R(3,3) is that the colored graph may contain a blue clique on 3 vertices, but no red clique on 3 vertices, or blue clique on 4 vertices. Indeed, it might be instructive for you to find such a coloring of a complete graph on 6 vertices.

Comment: I don't really understand since it is possible to find a clique of 4 nodes on K_6 where as you say it isn't possible which makes me slightly confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $R(3,4)$ you must find either a clique of size $3$ or an independent set of size $4$. The graph

```
   *    *    *
   |    |    |
   *    *    *
```

on $6$ vertices has neither a clique of size $3$ nor an independent set of size $4$. Every set of $3$ vertices contains two that are not adjacent, and every set of $4$ vertices contains two that **are** adjacent.

Comment: so from what i understand R(r,s) means that if there is an r clique there must therefore be an independent set of size s?

Comment: @a_confused_student: No, $R(r,s)$ is the smallest $n$ such that every graph on $n$ vertices has **either** an $r$-clique **or** an independent set of size $s$ (or both).

Comment: but in the example given we have an independent set of size 3 and so for R(3,4) we can say that for n= 6 we satisfy the definition you gave. I'm really sorry for giving so much trouble i'm really confused with all these definitions haha

Comment: @a_confused_student: No, it does **not** satisfy that definition. It does not have a $3$-clique, and it does not have an independent set of size $4$. You cannot interchange the two numbers.